# Has a *subalgebra of $L(H)$ with $1$ a trivial null space?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Like the title:
is it true that a self-adjoint unital subalgebra of $L(H)$ closed in the weak operator topology (a Von Neumann algebra) has a trivial null space? Why?
Thank you.

Comment: What would the null space be?

Comment: A null space of a set $S$ (in my case the set is the self-adjoint unital subalgebra of $L(H)$) is the set of the elements $\xi \in H$ such that $A\xi=0$ for all $A \in S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the unit of the subalgebra is the identity operator (that is, the algebra is non-degenerate), then the answer is yes: if $A\xi=0$ for all $A$, then in particular $\xi=I\,\xi=0$.

If the unit of the subalgebra is a projection $P\ne I$, then the null space is $(I-P)L(H) $.

Comment: Very clear! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.